# How do you set up remote autocompletion in Ext JS using a Direct store?

Tags: javascript, json, extjs, autocomplete, combobox

Aloha!

I'm busy working on a project and I've come across a problem: when using a data store with the proxy of type Direct, so, a DirectStore, as the source for a combobox, I am entirely unable to set up autocompletion, even after ensuring that mode: 'remote' is set.

After looking at the requests with Firebug, Chromium dev tools, and what have you, I do see that it is making a request back to the API router so the request is being made, but the problem is, it doesn't know that it's supposed to attach the text that I've typed into the autocomplete box to the JSON that is being sent back to the server.

So I guess my ultimate question is, is there any way that anyone here knows of so as to ensure that, even with a DirectStore, the proper data is sent so I can do some sorting or data targeting on the server backend? Thanks :D

Comment: Pls specify your concrete working version of ExtJS/Sencha.

Comment: Sorry for not clarifying. I'm using Ext JS 4.0.0

Answer (score 0):

With ExtJS 4.x you have two config options available when dealing with querying...

`queryMode`
and
`queryParam`

The first config option can be either `remote` (defaults to this anyway) or `local` and the second option lets you define what the name of the parameter is when using a remote query mode. Additionally, you can also set `queryMode` to `false` or `0` or an empty string, and this will cause **no** parameter to be sent to the server.